# Find number of matches in data frames with different categories in the same column

Tags: r, dataframe, match

I have two data frames with a column each having different or same categorical values as coded and illustrated below.

```
DF1 <- data.frame(Firm1 = c("A", "B", "C", "L", "M", "L"))

DF2 <- data.frame(Firm2 = c("L", "M", "N", "P"))

library(dplyr)
y <- DF1 %>% group_by(Firm1) %>% 
  dplyr:: summarise(n = n())

z <- DF2 %>% group_by(Firm2) %>% 
  dplyr:: summarise(n = n())
```

I tried using %in% logic but it isn't working. Some of the other pages that I checked on columns/data frames match also couldn't help. Kindly suggest how to get this coded. Thanks.

[image: Data and Output Ilustration]

Comment: I'm not entirely clear - are you looking to find the intersection of the two sets - `dplyr::intersect(setNames(DF1, "Firm"), setNames(DF2, "Firm"))` ?

Comment: you can use union, setdiff, and intersect. But be sure to use the same column names in all tables.

Comment: @thelatemail - Thanks. I need the union in the first column and the match between the data frame columns as the second one. The end objective is to find how many categories are common in the two data frames.

Comment: @RicVillalba - thanks, union would fetch the first column but I also need to get a match column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar approach to *@GKi*, but result is always sorted by firm.

```
x <- list(DF2$Firm2, DF1$Firm1)
data.frame(Firm=sort(do.call(union, x))) |> 
  transform(Match=c("No", "Yes")[Firm %in% do.call(intersect, x) + 1L])
#   Firm Match
# 1    A    No
# 2    B    No
# 3    C    No
# 4    L   Yes
# 5    M   Yes
# 6    N    No
# 7    P    No
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `union` and `intersect` and `%in%`.

```
. <- union(DF1$Firm1, DF2$Firm2)
data.frame(Firm = ., Match = c("No", "Yes")[1L + . %in% intersect(DF1$Firm1, DF2$Firm2)])
#  Firm Match
#1    A    No
#2    B    No
#3    C    No
#4    L   Yes
#5    M   Yes
#6    N    No
#7    P    No
```

Or somehow focusing on the method

```
x <- DF1$Firm1
y <- DF2$Firm2
. <- union(x, y)
#. <- sort(union(x, y)) #In case it should be sorted by firm (where was it asked for?)
data.frame(Firm = ., Match = . %in% intersect(x, y))
#  Firm Match
#1    A FALSE
#2    B FALSE
#3    C FALSE
#4    L  TRUE
#5    M  TRUE
#6    N FALSE
#7    P FALSE
```

Benchmark

```
bench::mark(jay.sf = local({x <- list(DF2$Firm2, DF1$Firm1)
data.frame(Firm=sort(do.call(union, x))) |> 
transform(Match=c("No", "Yes")[Firm %in% do.call(intersect, x) + 1L])}),
GKi = local({. <- union(DF1$Firm1, DF2$Firm2)
  data.frame(Firm = ., Match = c("No", "Yes")[1 + . %in% intersect(DF1$Firm1, DF2$Firm2)]) }),
GKiSort = local({. <- sort(union(DF1$Firm1, DF2$Firm2))
  data.frame(Firm = ., Match = c("No", "Yes")[1 + . %in% intersect(DF1$Firm1, DF2$Firm2)]) }) )
# expression      min  median itr/s…¹ mem_a…² gc/se…³ n_itr  n_gc total…⁴ result
#  <bch:expr> <bch:tm> <bch:t>   <dbl> <bch:b>   <dbl> <int> <dbl> <bch:t> <list>
#1 jay.sf        176µs   197µs   4931.    280B    21.3  2315    10   469ms <df>  
#2 GKi           114µs   122µs   7904.    280B    23.2  3752    11   475ms <df>  
#3 GKiSort       127µs   138µs   7005.    280B    23.2  3321    11   474ms <df>
```

Both variants of GKi are faster than the variant of jay.sf.